After importing an Azure Function app into API Management service, how do I view/edit the policy adding the generated host key authorizing calls?
I have imported an Azure Function app into Azure API Management service, which automatically generates a host key on the Function app for authorizing calls against it.
I would like to inspect the associated policy (if one exists) and edit it, but I can't find it anywhere - it's not shown in "Policy fragments".
How can I view/edit the policy that adds the generated function key to calls against the Function app?



is your issue resolved? @Shuzheng

No, it isn't @IkhtesamAfrin

I have posted my answer, please check @Shuzheng


Navigate to any operation which got added post importing a Function App in APIM. Lets say, in my case its HttpTrigger1. Then, click on Inbound processing policies --> </>.



This will give you below policy.

<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="afreeen-fa" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>


This policy signifies that, the operation is referring to a backend Id afreeen-fa which is created in APIs --> Backends blade of APIM instance.



Click on the backend name and then navigate to Authorization credentials to access the x-function-key which is being passed in request header when you invoke an operation in APIM test console.

This is how APIM is storing the function key after importing a function app and using it via set-backend-service policy.





Thank you! That makes sense. What exactly does the following directive do?
<set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="afreeen-fa" />

Do you know whether it's possible to import an Azure Functions app into API Management service (APIM) via Bicep? If not, then I need to import the OpenAPI spec, create the host key, add the host key in APIM, create the policy, etc. manually?

set-backend-service policy gets added automatically when you import a function app and creates a backend with the given backend id in Backends and store the function key in Named Values. You can also refer to this link to know more about the set backend policy and its functionality.

I believe, importing via bicep is not feasible at the moment but you can still verify the same with the product team. Have a look at this blog wherein its illustrated to use Import-AzApiManagementApi to import a function app in apim

Thank you, what do you mean by but you can still verify the same with the product team.?

Looked at your blog, but how do I ensure idempotent operations? The import would run in every single workflow run

I meant, you can check with the Microsoft APIM team about bicep import.

In the given blog powershell script is given to import the function app by using OpenAPI Json file and also you can add the set backend policy, named values by using powershell script

Microsoft APIM team - How would I get in contact with them?

I don't think it's possible to run the script multiple times, i.e. in each workflow run, similar to IaC

You can raise a github issue here

No, issues are not available there

I would start with checking Effective policy view to check if it's added by the policy. I'm guessing this is the case.
Select All operations or any operation, select the code view for policies and then select "calculate effective policy", this should show all the policies related to that operations.
I'm guessing that's either API level policy or Product level. Product policies can be checked and changed from Products-view and API lelve from "All operations" -level. There are also global policies but I don't think tis' there.


